# own test method in FunSuite in ScalaTest

Tags: scalatest

Currently FunSuite executes methods named as `test` as tests.

I would like to write a function `mytest` that wraps `test`. How can I make FunSuite recognise `mytest` as a test to be executed ?

Answer (score 2):

`FunSuite.test` is defined in *ScalaTest*'s `FunSpecLike` trait. It has the following definition:

```
protected def test(testName: String, testTags: Tag*)(testFun: => Any /* Assertion */)(implicit pos: source.Position): Unit = {
  // SKIP-SCALATESTJS-START
  val stackDepth = 4
  val stackDepthAdjustment = -2
  // SKIP-SCALATESTJS-END
  //SCALATESTJS-ONLY val stackDepth = 6
  //SCALATESTJS-ONLY val stackDepthAdjustment = -6
  engine.registerTest(testName, Transformer(testFun _), Resources.testCannotAppearInsideAnotherTest, "FunSuiteLike.scala", "test", stackDepth, stackDepthAdjustment, None, None, Some(pos), None, testTags: _*)
}
```

The most important point is that it registers its payload for execution, via the `engine.registerTest(...)` call. Theoretically, you could have it recognize `mytest` by doing something like this:

```
class MyFunSuite
extends FunSuite {

  // User-defined test named mytest
  protected def mytest(testName: String, testTags: Tag*)(testFun: => Any /* Assertion */)(implicit pos: source.Position) = {
    test(testName, testTags: _*)(testFun)(pos)
  }
}
```

You would then use it as follows:

```
class MyTests
extends MyFunSuite {

  mytest("This is one of my own tests.") {
    // ...
  }

  mytest("This is another test.") {
    // ...
  }

  // ...
}
```

That said, there's no added value here (as yet), and you're going to a lot of effort to just replicate the existing functionality. However, you could clearly modify the definition of `mytest` to perform some boilerplate actions that you may require.